# In react js; is there a way to call import within a function?

Tags: reactjs

There are a number of files which have a particular **basename** and a few **extensions** with each basename. I have defined a function which takes the basename as a prop. Problem is I am not able to use the props attribute to import the various files above the particular function I have defined. Import cannot be called within a function either. Please suggest something.

```
import fasta from '../genome_data/{props.id}.fna'
import fai from '../genome_data/{props.id}.fna.fai'
import gff  from '../genome_data/{props.id}.sorted.gff.gz'
import gfftbi from '../genome_data/{props.id}.sorted.gff.gz.tbi'
import ssrbw from '../genome_data/{props.id}.bw'
function View(props) {
const assembly ={
  name: '{props.id}',
sequence: {type: 'ReferenceSequenceTrack',
 trackId: 'GRCh38-ReferenceSequenceTrack',
  adapter: {
    type: 'IndexedFastaAdapter',
    fastaLocation: {
      uri: fasta,
   // and so on
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of importing it at the top of the file, require it later on. 
For example:

```js
const fasta = require(`../genome_data/${props.id}.fna`)

const assembly ={
  name: '{props.id}',
sequence: {type: 'ReferenceSequenceTrack',
 trackId: 'GRCh38-ReferenceSequenceTrack',
  adapter: {
    type: 'IndexedFastaAdapter',
    fastaLocation: {
      uri: fasta,
// and so on
```

Comment: thank you so much this worked. I am actually a biologist working within a tight deadline.  It's been hardly 2 months since I started learning about front end development. I've never done this before

Comment: no problem! just do me and the community back a favour and mark my answer as correct, thanks :D

Comment: I did! thanks once again for your help!